# Cannot run Jest (27.4.6) tests: defaultResolver is not defined by export

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, jestjs

After upgrading Angular version of my app to 12, I decided to upgrade other libraries like `jest` as well:

```
"jest": "^27.4.6", (from 24.1.0)
"jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
"jest-junit": "^13.0.0", (from ^9.0.0)
"jest-preset-angular": "11.0.1",
"jest-resolve": "^27.4.6", (added this one)
"ts-jest": "27.1.2" (from 24.0.0)
```

This is how my `jest.config.js` looks like:

```
const jestPresetAngularSerializers = require('jest-preset-angular/build/serializers');

module.exports = {
  name: 'sam-web',
  preset: '../../jest.config.js',
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/sam-web',
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      'jest-junit',
      {
        outputDirectory: 'reports',
        outputName: 'junit-sam-web.xml',
      },
    ],
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: [jestPresetAngularSerializers, 'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!lodash-es).+\\.js$'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/app/**/*.ts', '!src/app/**/*.module.ts'],
  cacheDirectory: '../../.jest-cache',
};
```

I'm also using `import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';` instead of `import 'jest-preset-angular';`

This is my app things and their versions:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.14
Node: 14.15.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.17
OS: win32 x64


Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.14
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.1.1
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
@angular/cli                       12.2.14
@angular/material                  12.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.2.13
@schematics/angular                12.2.14
rxjs                               7.4.0
typescript                         4.3.5
```

And this is the error what I get when I'm trying to run the tests:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Package subpath './build/defaultResolver' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\node_modules\jest-resolve\package.json
See "C:\Users\Dominik\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-9Gl1h1\angular-errors.log" for further details.
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I have tried to remove `node_module` and `yarn.lock`, clean cache, install everything one more time but every time is the same. I found a similar issue on some page where the solution was to run `npm update` but similar command for yarn doesn't help me. Maybe someone of you can help me?